# api request returns undefined

Tags: rest, vue.js, axios

maybe is a stupid question but,
when I'm calling api from 'outside' function it always returns undefined,
for example:

actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function getProducts() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products').then((response) => {
        return response;
    });
}
```

and then in a component:

```
mounted() {
        this.products = getProducts();
        console.log(this.products);
    }
```

returns undefined

of course when I make a request from component it returns result

```
mounted() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products').then((response) => {
            this.products = response;
            console.log(this.products);
        });
    }
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning the `response` value in the `then` callback of the `axios.get` call. However, your `getProducts` function doesn't return anything.

Simply return the `axios.get` call:

```
export function getProducts() {
  return axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/products');
}
```

Then, the result of `getProducts` will be the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by `axios.get()`. So, you can add a `then` callback on the result of `getProducts` and set you `this.products` that way:

```
mounted() {
  getProducts().then(products => this.products = products);
}
```

Comment: @null, wow I had really overthought this one. I've edited my answer with a much simpler solution.